# timestamps in milliseconds plot with matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib, timestamp

Hello i am trying to measure some RPC calls made with RabbitMQ to monitor times from :

- RPC starts from Producer (t1)
- Call enters the broker   (t2)
- Time that start the consumer to compute the thing that was asked (t3)
- Time that ends the computation (t4)
- Consumer response -> Producer (t5)

For the timestamp in the broker i used the RabbitMQ [Timestamp](https://github.com/rabbitmq/rabbitmq-message-timestamp)

So the timestamps that i got for a random RPC call are these

```
    "t1": 1580674842.503887,
    "t2": 1580674842511,
    "t3": 1580674842.511811,
    "t4": 1580674843.513187,
    "t5": 1580674843.520756
```

Now i would like to plot every time period with different color.
For example `t1-t2 blue`, `t2-t3 red`, etc. The problem that i have is that i can not manage to make them distinguishable. I tried with simple plot and scatter plot but the time periods llok too small. Any ideas ?

```
node = [1, 1, 1, 1, 1]
times = [t1, t2, t3, t4, t5]
plt.plot(times, node, color='r')
plt.scatter(times, node, color='b')
plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: T2 looks very large compared to the other time stamps.  Is t2 correct?

Comment: Yeap,  because it is the time that the called function takes to be executed. Compared to times that a call is transfer from point a to point b it quite bigger

Answer (score 0):

You can do this by separating data into 2 ranges because one of data is much larger than the others.

```
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt


data = {"t1": 1580674842.503887, "t2": 1580674842511, "t3": 1580674842.511811, "t4": 1580674843.513187, "t5": 1580674843.520756}

# plot data
fig, ax = plt.subplots(nrows=1, ncols=2)
fig.subplots_adjust(wspace=0)
times = [data.get('t1'), data.get('t3'), data.get('t4'), data.get('t5'), data.get('t2')]
colors = ['red', 'green', 'orange', 'yellow']
ax[0].scatter(times[0:-1], [0, 0, 0, 0], color=colors)
ax[1].scatter(times[-1], [0])
ax[1].set_yticklabels([])
ax[0].set_ylim(-1, 1)
ax[1].set_ylim(-1, 1)
ax[1].axhline(y=0, linestyle='--', color='lightgrey')
ax[0].axhline(y=0, linestyle='--', color='lightgrey')
plt.show()
```

**Output:**

[image]